# error: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c, hash, binary-tree, operands

I have a struct which I initialized = NULL here:

```
void inicializa(tabelaHash **tabela, int tamanhoTabela) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tamanhoTabela; i++) {
        inicializaArvore(&tabela[i]);
    }
```

My problem is that, when I test if it worked, with "if(tabela[i] == NULL) ..." on a function as the one I mentioned or any other that needs a "**tabela", it works just fine, but, when I do it on my main, it gets me this error:

```
main.c:129:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('tabelaHash'
  (aka 'struct sbb') and 'void *')
            if(tabela[k] == NULL)
               ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

the line that gets this error is just:

```
    for (k = 0; k < tamanhoTabela; k++) {
    129->if(tabela[k] == NULL)
        printf("funcionou");
}
```

tabela is a hash table of binary trees, tabelaHash is a struct sbb (sbb is a kind of binary tree defined as follows:

```
struct sbb {
tipoItem reg; //that is the information it holds
struct sbb *esq; // left pointer
struct sbb *dir; // right pointer
int esquipo; // if it is a vertical or horizontal pointer to the left
int dirtipo; // if it is a vertical or horizontal pointer to the right
```

};

I want to have a pointer that points to the root of each tree on the "tabela[i]", so I malloc'ed as follows:

```
tabelaHash *tabela;
tabela = malloc(tamanhoTabela * sizeof(tabelaHash*));
```

How do I test if tabela[i] is still NULL on my main?

edit: I don't know if that is of any help, but I have just realized that I can only use the "if(tabela[i] == NULL)" on a function if the function calls for a "tabelaHash **". If I call for a "tabelaHash *", than it gets me the same error.

Comment: You've given several disjoint code fragments that don't really present a complete picture of your problem, nor, indeed, of your question.  We generally prefer to see a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and serving as context for "how do I improve / fix / extend this" questions.  You will get better answers that way.

Comment: How is `tabelaHash` defined?

Comment: Also this `... sizeof(tabelaHash*)` mostly likely is wrong. It should be `... sizeof(tabelaHash)` or even better `... sizeof *tabela`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tabela` pointer is only a single pointer. As such when you do `tabela[k]` it gets the k'th `tabela` in the "array" of tables. The result of `tabela[k]` is thus a `tabelaHash`, which is not a pointer and thus can't be raw compared against NULL.

You may have wanted to write `tabelaHash **tabela;` instead...